# Hibernate modelmapper null value inserted

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, modelmapper

I'm starting to use Spring and Hibernate.

I have this Entity :

```
 public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;
    @NotEmpty
    private String password;
    @NotEmpty
    private String firstname;
    @NotEmpty
    private String lastname;
    @NotEmpty
    private String email;
    @ManyToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") })
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
}
```

and this DTO :

```
public class UserDTO {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private List<String> roles;
```

}

`Role` is like that (`RoleType` being an enum) :

```
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(unique = true)
    private RoleType name;

    public Role() {}
    public Role(RoleType name) {
        this.name = name;
}
```

}

Now, in my controller, I want to create a new user :

```
public void createNewUser(UserDTO user){      

    ModelMapper _modelMapper=new ModelMapper();

    User _newUser=_modelMapper.map(user, User.class);

    //SECOND PART  
    Set<Role> _roles=new HashSet<>();
    for (String _item : user.getRoles()) {
        RoleType _roleType=RoleType.valueOf(_item);
        Role _role=_roleRepository.findByName(_roleType);
        _roles.add(_role);

    }
    _newUser.setRoles(_roles); 

   _userRepository.save(_newUser);   
}
```

My concern is the second part (It does the trick but I'm not sure in term of good practices). I have 2 questions :

-is it the right way to fill the roles, being said that my `UserDTO` accepts a `List<String>` ?

-is it possible to map everything with the `ModelMapper` ? (I have tried but it fills my sql table only with the id, the name is null and it adds a line for each new user).

Thanks.